# Checking if the data already exist in the wp database

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm attempting to display a message in red colour if the data already exists in the database but it doesn't seem to be working. This is the code that I'm using.

PHP code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Add IP Address
 */
get_header(); 
?>
<?php

$sql="SELECT * FROM `wp_5wbtdj_ip_based_login` where (start='$start' or end='$end');";

      $res=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

      if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
        
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        if($end==isset($row['end']))
        {
                echo " End IP already exists";
        }
        if($start==isset($row['start']))
        {
            echo "Start IP already exists";
        }
        }
else{
    
//do your insert code here or do something (run your code)
}

If($_POST['Submit']){
            
    global $wpdb;
    
            
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $start = ip2long($_POST['start']);
    $end = ip2long($_POST['end']);
If($wpdb ->insert('wp_5wbtdj_ip_based_login', 
         array(
            'username' => $username,
            'start' => $start,
            'end' => $end
)
)== false) wp_die ('<div class="errormessage">Database insertion failed </div>');

else echo '<div class="successmessage"> Database insertion successfull </div>';

?>

<?php
}

else{
}

?>
```

HTML code:

```
<main role="main">
 <div class="section section_white section_nopadding_top">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <br><br>
     <div class="wrap">
      <form action="" id="postjob" method="post">
       <h3 style="margin-left:50px;">IP Based Login</h3>
       <hr />
        <h4 style="margin-left:50px;">Add IP Range</h4>
        <table class="form-table" style="margin-left:50px;">
         <tr>
          <th scope="row" valign="top">
           <label for="username">Username</label><br />
          </th>
         <td>
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
          <input type="text" size="25" name="username" value="<?php echo do_shortcode('[show_loggedin_as]'); ?>"><br /><br>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <div class="wrapper">   
          <th scope="row" valign="top">
           <label for="start_ip">Start IP </label>
          </th>
          <td>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
          <input type="text" minlength="7" maxlength="15" size="25" pattern="^((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$" name="start" valign="top" required>
         </div>
         <br><br>
        <tr>
         <div class="wrapper">   
          <th scope="row" valign="top">
           <label for="start_ip">End IP</label>
          </th>
          <td>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
            <input type="text" minlength="7" maxlength="15" size="25" pattern="^((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$" name="end" valign="top" required>
         </div>
          </td>
        </tr> 
        <br>
        </table><br />
<input name="Submit" class="button" value="Add IP range" type="Submit" style="margin-left:50px;"  />    
</form>
    </div>
<br /><br />
               </div> <!-- /col-md-12 -->
               
            </div> <!-- /row -->
            
         </div><!-- /.container -->
      </div> <!-- /section -->
   </main><!-- /.container -->

</div>
<?php
get_footer();
```

Can anyone help to point what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you write this code? If you're not writing this code yourself and just simply copy and paste from another source, its very hard for yourself to understand what the code is doing and definitely hard for you to debug it yourself. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Comment: What if one range overlaps another range?

Comment: I write this code my self

Comment: I'm sorry for assuming that you didn't write this code. That's just silly of me. I've made some edit to your question, I think that's what you really mean. However, if I wrote it incorrectly, please re-edit them.